# Remove relevant DOMTokenList item from array on button click

Tags: javascript, domtokenlist

I'm trying to figure out how to remove an item from an array on a button click. I've already figured out how to push the item to the array, but removing it is proving more difficult. The JS code is below:

```
let sideArray = [];
let sideButtons = document.querySelectorAll('div.side-buttons button');

for (let i = 0; i < sideButtons.length; i++) {
  if(sideButtons[i].textContent !== "RANDOM" ) {
    sideButtons[i].onclick = function (e) {
      //alert (this.innerHTML)

    this.classList.toggle('on');
    let tokenNum = this.className[0] + this.className[1];
    let index = sideArray.indexOf(tokenNum);
    if (this.classList.contains('on')) {

      sideArray.push(+(tokenNum));
      
      sortNumbers(sideArray);
      console.log(tokenNum);
      console.log(index);
      console.log(sideArray);

    } else if (!this.classList.contains('on')) {


      sideArray.splice(index, 1)
      sortNumbers(sideArray);
      console.log(sideArray);
    }
      let buttonHTML = this.textContent;

      //link to create choice button function
      //choiceButtons(buttonHTML)
    }
  }
}


function sortNumbers(array) {
  array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
}
```

Each button has a number as a class that helps me iterate through them. Once I push the relevant number to an array on click, I want to remove the relevant number from the array when the button is clicked a second time.
Can you help?

Edit: At it stands, the splice method removes the last element in the array, no matter which button you click.

Here's my code in full : https://codepen.io/david-webb/pen/JjXRqBQ

Comment: Sidenote: storing data like that as a class isn't ideal since you may not be able to rely on the order of classes, where multiple classes are set. Better would be to use a `data-*` attribute for the index.

Comment: So far as I can tell from your Fiddle, there's no problem. The item is removed the array as required after your `splice()` call. Additionally, your `else if` block can simply be `else`, since it represents the logical opposite of the `if` block.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, Mitya. It does remove an item, but it is always the last element in the array. I need the element to correspond with the number of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was the way you were gathering the token.

You're trying to gather the first and second characters of the button's class, but often there's only a first character - no second - so this produces a string like `4undefined`. We can fix this by retrieving the token via REGEX, allowing for any number of characters (1, 2, 6891, whatever).

I've fixed this and also refactored your code. This replaces your `for` loop. I've delegated the events, and also removed some unnecessary duplication.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    if (!evt.target.matches('div.side-buttons button') || evt.target.textContent == 'RANDOM') return;
    evt.target.classList.toggle('on');
    let tokenNum = evt.target.className.match(/\d+/); //<-- better way of getting token
    if (evt.target.classList.contains('on'))
        sideArray.push(tokenNum[0]);
    else {
        let index = sideArray.indexOf(tokenNum[0]); //<-- need this only in the else block, not if
        sideArray.splice(index, 1)
    }
    sortNumbers(sideArray);
    let buttonHTML = evt.target.textContent; //<-- you don't currently do anything with this
});
```

Comment: Thanks again, Mitya. I replaced my for loop with your code and it's causing the following error: ear.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined
    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> I can't see why, though - could you shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

I got around the issue with concatenating elements in the DOMTokenList by using this.className.split(' '). It's the same as my original code apart from that:

```
for (let i = 0; i < sideButtons.length; i++) {
  if(sideButtons[i].textContent !== "RANDOM" ) {
    sideButtons[i].onclick = function (e) {
    let textContent = this.textContent;

    this.classList.toggle('on');
    let classArray = this.className.split(' ')
    let buttonNum = +(classArray[0]);
    let index = sideArray.indexOf(buttonNum);
    if (this.classList.contains('on')) {
      sideArray.push(buttonNum);
      sortNumbers(sideArray);
      console.log(sideArray);
      orderButtons(sideArray, textContent);//*FOR SPLICING intervalArray

    } else {
      sideArray.splice(index, 1);
      orderButtons(sideArray);
      console.log(sideArray);
    }
  }
 }
}
```